# Почему двигатель гудит но не вращается?

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

Двигатель гудит но не крутится, бывает иногда прокручивается по чуть чуть но не периодично, пробовал на трех разных двигателях. Помогите исправить!  Подключил шаговый двигатель при помощи драйвера А4988 и NodeMcu V3 CH340 по следующей схеме

```
ДРАЙВЕР     NODEMCU
VMOT->      +питания,
GND ->      -питания,
B2,B1 ->    одна катушка двигателя,
A!, A2 ->   вторая катушка двигателя,
VCC ->      5V,
GND ->      GND,
STEP ->     D6,
DIR ->      D5,
```

Скетч написал ChatGpt, так как я не особо разбираюсь в arduino. Этот скетч сначала вращает шаговый двигатель в одном направлении на 5 секунд, а затем в другом направлении на 5 секунд, и так по кругу.

``

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Пины на NodeMCU для управления шаговым двигателем
#define DIR_PIN D5  // Пин направления движения
#define STEP_PIN D6 // Пин для установки шага

// Настройки шагового двигателя
#define STEPS_PER_REVOLUTION 200 // Количество шагов на оборот

// Время работы в каждом направлении (в миллисекундах)
#define RUN_TIME 5000 // 5 секунд

// Создаем объект для управления шаговым двигателем
AccelStepper stepper(AccelStepper::FULL4WIRE, STEP_PIN, DIR_PIN);

void setup() {
  // Инициализация шагового двигателя
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);         // Устанавливаем максимальную скорость (шагов/с)
  stepper.setAcceleration(500);      // Устанавливаем ускорение (шагов/с^2)
}

void loop() {
  // Вращение в одном направлении
  stepper.moveTo(STEPS_PER_REVOLUTION); // Устанавливаем позицию для движения
  stepper.runToPosition();              // Запускаем движение и ждем, пока не достигнем цели
  delay(RUN_TIME);                      // Ждем 5 секунд



// Вращение в противоположном направлении
  stepper.moveTo(-STEPS_PER_REVOLUTION); // Устанавливаем позицию для движения
  stepper.runToPosition();               // Запускаем движение и ждем, пока не достигнем цели
  delay(RUN_TIME);                       // Ждем 5 секунд
}
```

Comment: Обычно хорошие примеры кода прямо с библиотеками идут. ChatGPT, конечно, вам пургу напишет )